# Исходные коды java.*

Tags: java

На основе [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/187452/java-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-0x1-fffffffffffffp-2) сделал для себя открытие, что оказазывается java.* исходники открыты. **Где их скачать?** Гоголь ничего не нашёл. Конкретно интересует **java.util.Date**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Они поставляются вместе с JDK. Лежат в архиве src.zip в папке с JDK.